# Deleting blank page after title page

Tags: blank-page, amsbook

Using amsbook, I get a blank white page after the title page and before the TOC. Any way to delete this page? Many thanks.

Here is a MWE, for what it's worth:

```
 \documentclass[openany]{amsbook}

 \begin{document}

 \title{Title}

 \author{Author}

 \maketitle

 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{Start}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the table of contents in the verso page of the title page?

Comment: Yes, assuming I understand you correctly, that's exactly what I would like. (Just have the TOC start on the very next page after the title page, or on the back of it if thought of as a single sheet of paper.) I tried adding

    \documentclass[openany]{amsbook}

but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example?

Comment: Okay, added. Not sure that it's informative in this case…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a short (single page) table of contents is enough a `minipage`, but indeed [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) solution is better.

```
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\vfill
\tableofcontents
\end{minipage}
\chapter{Start}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this vertically misalignes the TOC.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to work provided the TOC isn't overly long. Mine splits over a page, and while putting it in a minipage as you suggest condences it to a single page, the blank page remains. (When I tweak it to make the TOC shorter, your trick works.)

Comment: @egreg. True. I forgot the `\vfill` after

Comment: @Skeptic. True also, I edited the answer accordingly

Answer (score 7):

The `amsbook` class reserves the verso of the title page for the abstract, the subject class information and the keywords. If you have nothing of this, you can patch the `\maketitle` (actually `\@maketitle`) command not to issue `\newpage`:

```
\documentclass[openany]{amsbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\newpage}{}{}{} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Start}

\end{document}
```